# Rail3 routes [edit problem]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

Example I have had configured my routes as

```
match '/cellphones/:permalink/:charger', :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'myaction'
resources :cellphones
```

Everything ok when I put something like this `localhost/cellphones/nokia3323/lion` but I can't edit a cellphone because have the same structure `localhost/cellphones/edit/4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes that are defined earlier take precedence, so you could make the edit route accessible again by reversing the order that you've declared your routes in. Since a route of `/cellphones/edit/:id` is more restrictive than `/cellphones/:permalink/:charger`, the edit route will match if the second part of the route is "edit" and pass through to your other route if it's something else.

However, you most likely don't actually have a `/cellphones/edit/:id` route, because what's created by `resources :cellphones` is `/cellphones/:id/edit` which is much harder to distinguish from `/cellphones/:permalink/:charger` since both have the wildcard part of the route as the second segment.

The easiest way the fix the problem would be to change the `/cellphones/:permalink/:charger` route so it's easier to distinguish. You could use something like `/cellphones/p/:permalink/:charger` ("p" for permalink), or anything else that's easy to distinguish from the RESTful routes created by `resources`.

There's a few other ways you could approach it as well, such as using [segment contraints](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#segment-constraints) or [adding more restful actions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions).

Comment: @utiq Make sure you accept this answer if it solved your problem. Just click the outline of a check box to the left of the question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, just had to change the order

```
resources :cellphones
match '/cellphones/:permalink/:charger', :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'myaction'
```